# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 + 1}{n\cdot2^{n-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $ \displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} \frac{n^2 + 1}{n\cdot2^{n-1}}$

I was able to reduce this series into the series of the form

$$ \sum _{n =1} ^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{n+1}{n\cdot2^{n-1}}$$

Evaluating the first part is simple (and there are many solutions to this on the internet), however I am not able to deduce the second part.

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28%28n%5E2%20%2B%201%29%2F%28n*2%5E%28n-1%29%29%29%20from%20n%20%3D%201%20to%20n%3Dinf), this series evaluates to $ 4 + \log 4$.

I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Hint $\int x^{n-1}= \frac{x^n}n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is split it in two

$$
\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} \frac{n^2 + 1}{n\cdot2^{n-1}}=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}_{=4}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{n}}_{=\log(4)}
$$

Edit : I don't know your math level so i'll start from scratch you can use that
$$
\frac{1}{n2^{n-1}}=2\frac{1}{n2^n}=2\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{k-1}\text{d}x
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k2^{k-1}}=2\sum_{k=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{1/2}x^{k-1}\text{d}x=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}x^{k-1}\text{d}x=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{1-x^{N}}{1-x}\text{d}x
$$
From this, you have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k2^{k-1}}=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{d}x}{1-x}-2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^{N}}{1-x}\text{d}x
$$
Making $N \rightarrow +\infty$, I let you show that
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x^{N}}{1-x}\text{d}x\underset{N \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k2^{k-1}}=2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{\text{d}x}{1-x}=\log\left(4\right)
$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you would evaluate $\frac{1}{n2^{n-1}}$. Perhaps could you explain that? That's pretty much the part I'm stuck on.

Comment: @talbi $(1-x)^{-2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...$

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Write it for the time being $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 + 1}{n}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}+\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}n$$

When done, make $x=\frac 12$